# How is the average time before collision $\tau$ and not $\frac{\tau}{2}$ in drift velocity?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-fields

wrt: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xfxEPjyIaZM&ab_channel=KhanAcademyIndia-English

$\tau$ is Relaxation Time (time between 2 successive collisions)

The video shows derivation of drift velocity of an electron as:
$$V= \frac{\sum (u + at)}{N}$$
where $V$ is drift velocity of an electron , $a$ is acceleration caused by electric field and $t$ is time since previous collison
$$V = \frac{\sum u}{N}+\frac{a\sum t}{N}$$
as initial velocity is random the average turns out to be zero
$$V= \frac{a \sum t}{N}$$
Now shouldnt $\frac{\sum t}{N} = \frac{\tau}{2}$as $0$ is the least possible time since previous collision and $\tau$ the maximum(on average $\tau$ is the time after which another collison occurs), so their mid value being $\frac{\tau}{2}$ instead of $\tau$

Comment: $\tau$ is the average, not the maximum

Comment: @Wolphramjonny , $\tau$ is the average time between a collision, let's say it is 4 seconds, this means on average after 4 seconds a new collision will occur and $t$(the time that has passed after a fresh collision) belongs to (0,4) the upper limit of $t$ can be a little less or more than 4 but on average it is 4. So if we randomly look at the electron at any instant in time we are more likely to find the electron to have traveled for 2 seconds since its previous collision.

Comment: no, a new collision will happen in $(0,\infty)$, with with $ \tau $being the typical value

Comment: you are confusing average with maximum

Comment: @Wolphramjonny , ok let say I have a car that starts at rest from point 'A' and moves till time 'T' to get at point 'B; with constant acceleration of 1m/s^2 , now the final velocity of the car at point 'B' is T(as initial velocity was 0). Now would you say that the average velocity of the car when travelling from A to B was T(it's final velocity) or (0+T)/2 = T/2? Now lets say I kept on repeating this experiment while I change the value of T a little bit but the most typical value would still be T. Lets record all these observations , now will the average of these observations be T or T/2?

Comment: It will be T/2, for the same reason that the average is $\tau$

Comment: $\tau$ is already the average, not the maximum. And actually $\sum t /N$ is the definition of average